# What is a function independent of a variable?

Tags: functions

I am having trouble to interpret if a given functions if independent of a parameter or not.
Suppose $f(x) = x^2$ and $x = cy$. I ask you, is this function $y$ independent?
I don't know if it is a misinterpretation of the literature or not, but i am not sure how to answer.

You can tell me yes, since $y$ varies, $x$ varies and $f$ varies. But i could reply that no, $f$ varies because $x$ varies, not because $y$ varies.

I am a little confused

Comment: Could not you say that your function is the composition $f((cy)^2)$?Your function depends on $y$. You have $f(x(y))$.

Answer (score 1):

This $y$ is *not* a function. It may be the i*ndependent variable* of a certain function $$g:\quad y\mapsto x=g(y):=c\,y\ ,$$ which maps the $y$-space into the $x$-space. The $\>c\>$ here is a *parameter*, i.e., a  constant whose numerical value is immaterial  for the algebraic calculations.

From the two functions $$f: \quad x\mapsto z=f(x):=x^2$$ and $g$ one may form the composed function
$$h:=f\circ g:\qquad y\mapsto z=f\bigl(g(y)\bigr)=(cy)^2=c^2y^2\ .$$
Depending on the circumstances, the function $g$ is not viewed as an actual map, but as a change of coordinate, say due to a change of the measuring unit. In such a case people sometimes call the $h$ again $f$, so that now $f$ appears as "function  $z=f(y)$". This can lead to mistakes when applying the chain rule.